# grep inverted match on the file and not on a line by line match

Tags: linux, files, grep

I have a set of files that contain some information.
I am interested in the subset of files that do **not** contain a specific pattern at all.
E.g.

```
cat file.txt  
foo  
bar  
trivial information
some customer data
```

let’s say that I am interested in files that do not have the line ‘trivial information’.
How would I do that?
If I do:

```
grep -v ‘trivial information’
```

it will not work because the rest of the lines in the file are match to this inverted search so the `file.txt` will end up in the result.
So how do I do an invert match on the whole file and not line by line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for the `-L` flag:

```
grep -L 'trivial information' *
```

From `man grep`:

> -L, --files-without-match
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from  which no  output  would  normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.

Comment: I wish I remembered that switch in the future, I've done `for f in ... grep $p $f >/dev/null || echo $f` a couple of times...